# Embbedable hibernate annotation is not working

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, persistence

I am actually learning hibernate, and I think that @Embbebed and @Embbedable its not working for me

I got this:

[image]

```
@Entity
public class Poi {
@Id @GeneratedValue
private long id;

@Embedded
private PoiType poiType;

private String name;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private Poi(){}

public Poi(PoiType type,String name) {
    this.poiType = type;
    this.name = name;
}
```

---

```
@Embeddable
public class TypeA extends PoiType {

private Integer number;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private TypeA(){}

public TypeA(Integer num) {
    this.number=num;
}
```

---

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" 
    version="1.0"> 


<persistence-unit name="db" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>


    <class>tpAnual.POIs.Poi</class>
    <class>tpAnual.POIs.PoiType</class>
    <class>tpAnual.POIs.TypeA</class>



    <properties> 
    <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>        

        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" /> 
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:app-db" /> 
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="sa" /> 
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="" /> 
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />


        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" /> 
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" /> 
        <property name="use_sql_comments" value="true" /> 
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />

    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

When I run a test (everything setted correctly) the console out only prints:

> Hibernate: 
>       insert 
>       into
>           Poi
>           (id, name) 
>       values
>           (default, ?)

What do am I missing? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance in embedded entities hardly makes sense, because it calls for a different set of columns in the containing entity table depending on the actual class of the embedded entity, but at the time of declaration, the ORM does not know anything about the classes that may be derived from the base class that you want to make embedded.  I hear that EclipseLink somehow does it, (I don't want to even think of what kind of evil deeds they do to pull that trick,) but as far as I know, hibernate does not support it.